# Recaptcha error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, recaptcha

I have a problem with [Recaptcha](https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha) gem. I'm using Ubuntu on a virtual machine (VirtualBox). It uses bridged network interface card, so I have internet access there and I can see this Ubuntu from my host computer.

When I run **rails s** and than go to

- 127.0.0.1:3000 on virtual machine everything is fine.
- 192.168.0.103:3000 on host machine there is an error with recaptcha box.

**Input error: Invalid referer** is where the box is supposed to be.

Why is it like that and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But, when we tried to host the same application to any server with the same pair of keys, it will not generate an error but, it will display like "input error - invalid referer" instead of captcha in your form.

Because, when we are getting the pair of keys from Google API, we will specify the domain name there. In that, to use those keys in your local system, we will enter domain as "localhost". But, these pair of keys will not work when we deploy that application in any server.

So, for the application to work in the remote host, we should get the pair of keys from Google API with the domain name, where we are going to deploy your application. And use them in your application.

**Note:**
We can have a new pair of keys for recaptcha using following link:
http://www.google.com/recaptcha/whyrecaptcha